# Oracle sql- replace null with next and p

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to `UPDATE` a table and replace `NULL` values but with certain conditions. I created an example below and order it by cases to help illustrate where my conditions apply.

1º - In case there is a `NULL` value it is supposed to replace with the previous known value. (CASE 1-3)

2º - When there are two consecutive `NULL` and the `ID` changes. I expect it to go pick the previous known value from `ID 5` and the next from `ID 6`, no matter which `DATE`. (CASE 4-5)

```
ID     DATE     HOUR   VAL        CASE
--  ---------- ----- -------     ------
5   2015.03.29  16   15.45         1
5   2015.03.30  13   NULL          2
5   2015.03.30  14   33.45         3
5   2015.03.31  15   NULL          4
6   2015.02.27  03   NULL          5
6   2015.02.27  04   76.77         6
```

This is how it is supposed to look like:

```
ID     DATE     HOUR   VAL        CASE
--  ---------- ----- -------     ------
5   2015.03.29  16   15.45         1
5   2015.03.30  13   15.45         2
5   2015.03.30  14   33.45         3
5   2015.03.31  15   33.45         4
6   2015.02.27  03   76.77         5
6   2015.02.27  04   76.77         6
```

I already managed to do my 1º condition, though I can't see how I am going to implement the CASE 4-5. I've tried so many ways and I can't understand how to do it.

Even though I'm doing an `UPDATE` here, in case someone knows how to do it with just `SELECT`, I can export the results and then `INSERT` it again, but if you can add to this query I appreciate. Thanks for any help!

```
MERGE INTO DADOS t1
USING (
    SELECT rowid rd, "ID", "DATE", "HOUR",
           last_value( "VAL" ignore nulls )
           OVER (order by "DATE"
                 rows between unbounded preceding and current row
           ) as newVAL
    FROM DADOS
) x
ON (t1.rowid = x.rd)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1."VAL" = x.newVAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this query in your `merge` statement, it produced desired output:

```
select id, tdate, hour, coalesce(val, v1, v2) val 
  from (
    select id, tdate, hour, val, 
        lag (val ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by tdate, hour) v1,
        lead(val ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by tdate, hour) v2
      from dados)
  order by id, tdate, hour
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3003d/1)</sup>